# Task List not giving me what I expect

Tags: c#, .net, task

When I run the following I get the value of 100 for Task #{0} and cb

If I debug line by line in the loop then I get the correct answer.

How to fix this?

```
public static void TaskList()
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> cb = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    List<Task> taskArray = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        taskArray.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Object obj) => {
            int j = 0 + i;
            cb.Add(j);
            Debug.WriteLine("Task #{0} created on {1}",
                                j, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        },
                                                i));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskArray.ToArray());
    foreach(var v in cb)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(v);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the sleep?

Comment: @jdweng I am just simulating a task that will take some time.  And clearly the task does more than produce i (well j).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a modified closure (`i`) inside your tasks.

When the `Task` is effectively executed the value of `i` is not determinated (in your case, it is 100 because the task starts after your `for` loop finishes).

You must avoid to capture modified closures inside delegates which are executed lazily (your `Task` snippet is an example, but the same could happen using LINQ on `IEnumerable`).

Instead, assign your value to a local variable and pass it inside the `Task` action:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var count = i;
    taskArray.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Object obj) => {
        int j = 0 + count;
        cb.Add(j);
        Debug.WriteLine("Task #{0} created on {1}",
                            j, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    },
                                            i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing `100` getting print out for almost every run because the `i` in the following line is equivalent to 100 by the time the tasks are getting run:

```
int j = 0 + i;
```

I believe you're attempting to alleviate this problem with your `int j = 0 + i` line, but since the `i` is what's getting changed, `j` will still always be equivalent to whatever `i` is when the task is run. If you assign the value of `i` to `j` *outside* of your task, then you won't see this issue:

```
int j = i;

taskArray.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Object obj) => {
    cb.Add(j);
    Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created on {1}",
                        j, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}, , i));
```

Not sure I did a great job of explaining that, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure who was first

Comment: @paparazzo Federico beat me by a few seconds. Thanks for the upvote :)